# error generate in SonarFramework.h #include "extensions/cocos-ext.h" file not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

I using the cocos2dx c++ for game devlepoment.Now I want implement  sharing in game.I add the sonarcocoshelpercpp folder in class folder and social.framework in framework folder then gnerate the error on sonarFremework.h file that is "extensions/cocos-ext.h" file not found.Any solution for this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check the Header Search Paths under Build Settings for the build target that is emitting this error, and ensure that the headers list includes all the relevant cocos folders.

If you installed your project using the Cocos Launcher then the first (and for that #include critical) entry should be

```
/Applications/Cocos/frameworks/cocos2d-x-3.7
```

(Assuming, from the tags, that this is a XCode on Mac project)

Comment: yes i am using the xcode mac project. I develope the game in cocos2dx 2.2.6. In my project the Header Search Pathe like this:

Comment: cocos2d-x 2.2.6? With (such) an old version of cocos I would wonder if it is supported by sonarcocoshelpercpp?